# Value of $\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\lfloor(x-\frac{\pi}{2})/\cos x\rfloor$

Tags: calculus

$$\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}{2}}\left\lfloor\frac{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cos x}\right \rfloor$$

After I took the Right Hand Limit by using 
$$\lim_{h\to0} \left\lfloor\frac{\frac{\pi}{2}+h-\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cos({\frac{\pi}{2}+h)}}\right\rfloor$$

I got $$\lim_{h\to0} \left\lfloor {\frac{h}{-\sin h}}\right\rfloor$$

From here onwards I am confused whether my answer is $-1$ or $-2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\pi>h>0$
$$ \sin(h)< h $$
For $-\pi<h<0$
$$\sin(h)> h $$
From this, for $h\neq 0, -\pi<h<\pi$
$$ \frac{h}{\sin(h)} > 1 \implies -\frac{h}{\sin(h)}< -1$$
As $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h}{\sin(h)} = 1 $$
For $h$ close enough to $0$, $-\frac{h}{\sin(h)}$ is close to $-1$, so that
$$-2\leq-\frac{h}{\sin(h)}< -1 \implies \left\lfloor \frac{h}{\sin(h)} \right\rfloor = -2 $$
More formally, from definition of a limit, there exists $\delta>0$ for which 
$$ 0<|h|<\delta \implies -2\leq-\frac{h}{\sin(h)} $$

And the limit is $-2$, we can take $\min\{\delta, \pi\}$ for this limit.

Comment: I have one doubt about the equality sign of  $-\frac{h}{\sin(h)}< -1$ , how it is $\ge -2$ , it can be greater than -2

Comment: Can we say that -$\frac{h}{sinh}$ $\in $(-2,-1)

Comment: For $0<|h|<\delta$, where $\delta$ is the one in the answer, we can say that $-\frac{h}{\sin(h)}\in[-2, -1)$. Yes, it can be greater, and we can choose, maybe smaller, $\delta_0>0$, for which $-\frac{h}{\sin(h)}\in(-2, -1)$. This doesn't change anything in our proof though. In fact, for any $x<-1$, we can choose $\delta_0>0$ such that $-\frac{h}{\sin(h)}\in(x, -1)$.

Comment: I have one doubt. For $h<0$, $sin(h)>h$, which implies $h/sin(h)<1$, which should imply $-h/sin(h)>-1$.But your sixth line disagrees with my reasoning . Please clarify .

Comment: @Alphanerd I'm sorry, I noticed a mistake. $\sin(h)<0$ for $-\pi<h<0$, so in the expression $\sin(h)>h$, if we try to divide by $\sin(h)$, we need to change signs.